# LightSwitch in Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-lightswitch

I wanted to try developing projects in LightSwitch and download Visual Studio 2013 Community edition which has same features as Professional but there is no LightSwitch project template. 
Should i need to download seperatly ?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found the below link. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2014/11/12/develop-lightswitch-and-cloud-business-apps-using-visual-studio-community-2013.aspx

You need to  Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 – November Update.

Comment: It makes little sense to me, but it worked for me too - thanks!

Comment: As for VS Community 2015, Office Dev Tools for VS 2015 is needed as pointed out here, pointing the obvious but, as referenced [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs): "Requires installation of the Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2015 that are available at RTM."